# Need help applying euclidean algorithm to polynomials

Tags: number-theory

I don't understand how the euclidean algorithm can be used to find the gcd of two polynomials in the following example:

$x^3-27=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)$

$2x^3-11x^2+16x-3=(x-3)(2x^2-5x+1)$

so we expect the gcd to be $(x-3)$

performing long division,

$2x^3-11x^2+16x-3=2(x^3-27) -11x^2+16x+51$

$x^3-27=-x/11(-11x^2+16x+51)$

and then i am unsure where to go from here